# How to calculate the theoretical running time of insertion sort, for any input n?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

Note that I'm using insertion sort as an example, here. I've been given an assignment in my C.S. class which involves comparing the resulting run-times of various sorting algorithms with the *theoretical run-times* which should occur.

For example, let's say I have an input array of 1000 randomly ordered integers, and I'm operating under the assumption of a worst-case scenario. The result may be somewhere around `320.x milliseconds`. Yet, theoretically, it should be a flat `300 milliseconds`. Likewise, if I bump up the input size to 6000, I could get `11,735.577106 milliseconds` (as shown in the example provided by my C.S. teacher); the theoretical running time, however, would be `10,800 milliseconds`.

We know that worst-case performance of insertion-sort is `f(n) = O(n^2)`. Not aware of the original definition of `f`, I looked it up and found the result to be,

`f(n) = ( n(n - 1) + n ) / 2 = n^2 / 2`.

Which leads me to the recurrence relation for the algorithm:

`T(n) = T(n-1) + f(n)`

So, I decided to write a little C program and test `T(n)` with an input of 1000, expecting to get around 300000 or so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Recurrence relation for insertion sort ( worst-case )
float T( float n )
{
    if ( n == 1.0f )
        return 1.0f;

    return T( n - 1 ) + n * n * 0.5f;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "T( %f ) = %f \n", 1000.0f, T( 1000.0f ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
T( 1000.000000 ) = 166916608.000000
```

Clearly, this wasn't the case.

So, I'm stumped.

**tl;dr**

*I'd like to know how my professor arrived at 300 milliseconds for a theoretical run-time, using an insertion sort of an array of 1000 elements. My understanding is that recurrence relations are used to solve this, yet the output of the code shown (which is supposed to be the recurrence relation of insertion sort's worst-case) doesn't provide any clear means of easily understanding how this actually is computed.*

Comment: how are you measuring time? And the numbers you posted were averaged over many runs? How did you compute the theoretical number? Was it based on your machine's clock speed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the worst case scenario, create a array that is sorted descendingly and use insertion sort to have an ascending sort.

Your best case scenario would be if you take an ascending sorted array and try to run it through insertion sort.

Get the benchmarks for both of them and try to correlate them.

Also O(n^2) does not equal exactly n^2 operations . In Big-O notation, both O(2(n^2)) and O((n^2)/2) will be represented as O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence is not right; to count comparisons in the worst case, it should be T(0) = 0; T(n) = T(n - 1) + n - 1, because it takes n - 1 comparisons in the worst case to insert into a sorted array of length n - 1. The solution is T(n) = n (n - 1)/2. Your recurrence has cubic complexity, which is why the program's output is way off.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to define how Insertion Sort works, which will show us how it grows over Time.

**Insertion Sort** is an algorithm that takes a list of n numbers, and insert them one by one into a new list (initially empty) making sure that each number is inserted into its place, ending up with an ordered list.

- First thing to notice is that we read every number from the list once, this means we have `n` first.
- Then for each number we read, we first insert into the end of the list, so that's `1` operation.
- Then we have to compare it with previous value in the new list, if it's less than the previous value, we swap and repeat until the condition invalidates, so that's `1+3` operations for each compare & swap, but how many compare & swap we have is the question.
- We will consider all non-variant operations as a constant `C`.
- We consider the worst case, and in the worst case, every number turns out that it has to be shifted to the start of the list.
- For the `i`th number read, the worst case is that it has to shift `i-1` times, where `1 <= i <= n`.

So in total we have:

```
Time = T(shift(1)) + T(shift(2)) + .. + T(shift(n))

Time = C * (0 + 1 + 2 + .. + (n-1))

Time = C * (1/2 (n-1)n)

Time = C * (1/2 n^2 - 1/2 n)
```

Then we take time complexity into asymptotic Big-O:

```
Time ~ O(C * (1/2 n^2 - 1/2 n)) = O(n^2)
```